# Why am I getting a "Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer" error?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting the following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49722/devtools/browser/e3cdef84-2a4f-4829-8cb2-4baf45efa446
[0903/065243.722:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(122)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
```

When setting ChromeDriver as the webdriver:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER, chrome_options=options)
```

The rest of the scraping script seems to run fine. Should I be concerned? Is there a way to ensure this doesn't come up?

Answer (score 4):

While I'm trying to fix my own problems with headless Chrome, I stumbled over your question.

Adding `--disable-gpu` to the arguments will disable GPU-based/assisted rendering and only use a software render.

This solved the problem with that error message for me.

You'll find an extensive list of command line switches here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 0):

I once got the same error while building my electron.js app. (Chromium)

In combination with: "ERROR: viz_main_impl.cc(186) Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization"

--disable-gpu did work for me too, to get rid of this error, but the performance was horrible then.

After looking into it a bit, it turned out, that my Debian version was to old for my cpu (with integrated gpu), so it could not use the gpu. Only the software render.
--> Update to newest Debian Version, and everything worked.

[electron](/questions/tagged/electron) [chromium](/questions/tagged/chromium)