# How to plot animated matplotlib in html with mpld3

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, mpld3

I want to show a graphs that is monitoring a sensor data in my raspberry pi in a html page. I have been using matplotlib graphs and recently I have installed mpld3 library but I the code shows me this error:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[2786:2888:0217/042317.744817:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2022 04:23:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2838:2838:0217/042319.282873:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[1:8:0217/042319.671753:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2022 04:23:20] "GET /d3.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2022 04:23:20] "GET /mpld3.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2022 04:23:21] code 404, message Not Found
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2022 04:23:21] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

And the code that I'm running is this:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import mpld3

fig = figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4])

mpld3.show(fig)
```

What is my error? Or if you know how to show matplots graphs in html only with python and html!

thanks!

Comment: First of all, there is nothing wrong with your code. It looks like a Chromium [issue](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-portablelinux/issues/2). What's your Linux distribution and Chromium version ?

Comment: I am using Raspbian as OS and my Chromium version is 72.03626.121 (Build Oficial) running on Raspbian 9.9 (32 bits)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `mpld3.enable_notebook()`. The documentation says "This is useful if you want every figure to be automatically embedded in the notebook as an interactive JavaScript figure." You can find other resources [here](http://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html).

1 - In regards to your Chromium error, see [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236020).

2 - In regards to your Sandbox error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69037769/13542462).

3 - In regards to your GPU error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66077453/13542462).